# To find the number of ordered pair such that $B \cup C = A$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A = \{a, b, c, d, e\}$. If two non empty subsets $B$ and $C$ of set $A$ are formed (without replacement of elements) such that $B \cup C = A$ then how to find the number of such ordered pairs $(B, C)$ can be formed.

Comment: Is there something wrong in the answer ?   If you wish I can explain any aspect

Answer (score 3):

Each element has $2$ choices, to be part of set $B$, or to be part of set $C$. Since there are $5$ elements, we will have $2^5 = 32$ ways. But given that $B \ne \phi$ and $C \ne \phi$, we exclude two of these possibilities, so the final answer will be $\color{blue}{30}$ such splits.

Comment: You have counted the number of distributions of disjoint sets such that $B \cup C = A$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig. I will certainly give it a thought, but wouldn't your answer numerically equal to the same number ?

Comment: I now see why you answered as you did.  You understood, correctly, that without replacement of elements means that the sets $B$ and $C$ must be disjoint.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig. thank you. You need not have deleted your answer

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misread the problem and counted distributions in which $B$ and $C$ have non-empty intersections in addition to the pairs in which $B$ and $C$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Each element has to either go in set A or in set B.  That's 2 choices for each of the 5 elements.

Comment: We also have to take into consideration that neither $B$ nor $C$ is allowed to be empty.